# How to use OMRON (D6T-1A-02) on Raspberry Pi on GitHub

Tags: c, github, raspberry-pi

I am a 4th year college student. I had a problem last week, and I couldn't find a solution on the website.

#### Assumptions

- I want to run the temperature sensor OMRON (D6T-1A-02) demo code on Raspberry Pi
- Ubuntu is installed on Raspberry Pi 4

#### What I want to achieve

[d6t-2jcieev01-raspberrypi](https://github.com/omron-devhub/d6t-2jcieev01-raspberrypi)
I want to run the demo code of

if you succeed (but I can not do right now)

```
PTAT: 27.2[degC], Temperature: 27.5, 27.3, 27.3, 27.3, 27.2, 27.1, 27.1, 27.2, 27.1, 27.1, 27.3, 27.3, 27.0, 27.2, 27.3, 27.0, [degC]
```

#### Problem/Error Message

> $ ./d6t-1a

When I did it, the temperature is not output, and the following is output was showed many times.

```
Failed to open device: Permission denied​

PEC check failed: DF(cal)-00(get)​

PTAT: 0.0 [degC], Temperature: 0.0, [degC]
```

#### Tried

1. I completed Soldering so, hardware was completed.
2. I followed github procedure written in the official manual (I hope that you click to see the procedure)

[d6t-2jcieev01-raspberrypi](https://github.com/omron-devhub/d6t-2jcieev01-raspberrypi)

·clone

> $ unzip d6t-2jcieev01-raspberrypi-master.zip

・make

> $ cd d6t-2jcieev01-raspberrypi-master
> $ make all
> I was able to do it until

Then I ran

> $ ./d6t-1a

and I got the error:

So, I set the I2C speed to 100kHz or less from the boot config.txt as shown on github, but the result is the same.

What can I try next?

Comment: You mentioned "I got the error:", but forgot to put the error text. Would you add it?

Comment: It looks like you're getting a permissions error. This sounds like a basic Unix permission problem: you probably need write access to something in `/dev`. If you run your code as `root` and the problem goes away, that would positively identify this as the problem.